# Questions with accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, api, questions, answers

I know that you could technically loop through the answers returned when you ask for `/questions/{id}` to see if an answer has been accepted, but it would be AWESOME if there was a top level boolean `hasAccepted` or something of that nature. How bout it, guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "accepted_answer_id" for questions method. When there is no accepted answers,that field does not exists in returned JSON. So `hasAccepted` is the existance of `"accepted_answer_id"` field.